# how can js go from white to blue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a menu that when you hover other menu item, there is a change from a white color to a tone of blue. I was thinking to use opacity, but had no luck, what would you suggest?

[I am using this code](http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/222/)

HTML

```
 <nav>
        <ul class="showcase">
        <li><a href="#" class="current">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">5</a></li>

        </ul>
        </nav>​
```

CSS

```css
nav ul li a{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    font-weight:normal;
    display:block;    /* IE6, IE7 line height fix */
    padding:15px;
    background-color:transparent;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:6px;
    text-decoration:none;    
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #43AEF2;
    padding:15px;
    color:white;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

nav ul li a.current{
    background-color:#43aef2 ;
    padding:15px;
    color:white;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

​
JS

```
$("li").css('opacity', '1')
$(".selected").css('opacity', '.9')

$('ul.showcase').hover(

function() {
    $(this).find('li').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('li').stop().fadeTo(500, .8);
})​
```

Comment: You can do it with just css http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/220/

Comment: Question title: how can js go from white to blue? Consider rephrasing.

Comment: sorry I posted uncorrect jsfiddle. I updated it

Comment: is that what you want http://jsfiddle.net/VYtqC/ only in css

Comment: I didn't make my point clearly enough. Js, ie. the language javascript, *can't* go from white to blue. You want js to cause some DOM element to animate from white to blue. The title should be something like "Animate color with jQuery" (for which a jQuery plugin is required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure about your excepted outcome but give this a try:

```
$("li").css('opacity', '0.40');
$(".selected").css('opacity', '1');

$('ul.showcase > li').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
}, function () {
    $(this).not('.selected').stop().fadeTo(500, 0.40);
})​;​
```

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/mdamC/228/

Comment: Almost the result expected, but How can you let the menu item (in the examples the numbers 1,2,3,4,5) be black instead of going gray always?

Comment: @cMinor Are you talking about the text (i.e the numbers 1,2,3,4,5) or something else?

Comment: Yes exactly, how to keep the text in black and do not let it go gray

Comment: To clarify you never want it to go gray so it's always black after you hover over it?

Comment: I don't think that will be possible because the text is contained within the element the opacity is being set on, which means all elements inside it will basically have an opaque layer over them. Which is what makes the font color look grey.

Comment: If you were to set a callback and just remove the opacity layer this is what you would get: http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/mdamC/240/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using css3, you may consider using a tranisition effect for the hover, e.g.:

```
nav ul li a:hover{
    -webkit-transition: background-color linear 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color linear 1s;
    -ms-transition: background-color linear 1s;
    transition: background-color linear 1s;
    background-color: #43AEF2;
    padding:15px;
    color:white;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

And after clicking the link:

```
$('ul li a').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parents('ul').find('li a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/fkPrW/)

Answer (score 0):

i would go with @elclanrs suggestion but in your code wondering why you selecting the whole ul instead for each li element

```
$('ul.showcase li').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, .8);
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead "hover" i would prefer "mouseenter" and "mouseleave"
http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/226/

```
    $('ul.showcase li').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(1,1);
    })
    $('ul.showcase li').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(1,0.4);
    })
```